# using xBind with MapElementLayer

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

Let's say I have two classes: 
Paths and Pins, that I want to represent on the map. Both are POCOs with latitude and longitude. 
What's the best way to create two layers of MapElements that I can display on the map independently?

Currently I manually create an ObservableCollection of MapElements for each type of items I wish to display on the map. Then I populate the collection with MapElements using data from POCOs

The problem is that, when position of one of these items updates, I have to manually update each MapElement.
Is it possible to use xBind to update each mapelement? For example by generating a collection of MapElements in XAML?

Comment: Have you checked this [documation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#add-xaml)?

Comment: Yes, in that example the objects are added to the map manually, and no updating is shown.